# How does the cited passage of Aristotle imply that what exists sempiternally cannot age?

Tags: aristotle, time, necessity

[This](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5585373/mod_resource/content/1/Eternity.pdf) article from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy indicates Aristotle's position as "what exists sempiternally cannot age. (Physics 221b30)"

The Hussey translation of the cited passage from Book IV of Physics (with context):

> 221b23. It is manifest, therefore, that not everything that is not will
> be in time either; for example, all the things that cannot be other- wise [than not being], like the diagonal's being commensurate with the side. For in general, if time is a measure in itself of change and of other things accidentally, it is clear that all things of which it measures the being must have their being in being at rest or changing. Now all things that admit of ceasing-to-be and coming-to-be and, generally, that at some time are and at some time are not, must be in time-there will be some greater time which will exceed both their being and that [time] which measures their being. But, of things that
> are not, all that time surrounds either were (e.g. Homer once was)
> or will be (e.g. something future), on whichever side [of the present] it may surround them; and if on both sides, both. But all the things
> that it nowhere surrounds neither were nor are nor will be; and, among things that are not, such are all those that are such that their contraries always are: e.g. the diagonal's being incommensurable s always is, and this will not be in time. So its being commensurable
> will not be [in time] either; so that always is not being opposite to what always is. But everything of which the opposite not always is, is capable of being and of not being, and there is coming-to-be of it and ceasing-to-be.

It is not clear to me how the cited passage implies the stated characterization of what exists sempiternally (i.e., that it cannot age). How does the cited passage imply this aspect of what exists sempiternally?

Comment: It seems to mean that there are "things out of time", like the truth of arithmetic and geometry,that are eternal and immutable, as well as their negation. The first ones exist sempiternally,  the second one do not exist sempiternally.

Comment: In both case, being sempiternal, they are out of time, and thus they are not subjext to the processes of "coming to be" and "passing away".

Comment: "aging" like "growing" are processes that happen in time. They do not affect the eternal truths.